# Is it possible to generate a new mysite space with the Web Services?

Tags: 2010, web-services, my-site

I need to generate a mysite space upon account creation. As of today, once the account has been created, user is redirected to `/_layouts/mysite.aspx` generating the mysite.

I need to call this creation remotely and Web Services seemed the solution, but i can't find any useful method.

Another solution would be to call the `/_layouts/mysite.aspx` in an ajax call and check for the result when creation's done.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an event that is run when the user logs into their mysite.

With this in mind you can fetch the mysite as the user to simulate logging in.

I haven't really looked into a more elegant way of doing this, but there perhaps may be.

This is the basis of all my warm up scripts for powershell and mysites, it's really quick when run on a local machine, and there is no reason why this can't be done remotely or in a service/event receiver.

Comment: So if i'd issue a SOAP request to the `_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx?WSDL`, the site would get created?

Comment: That method, I haven't tested. I doa  http request with ntlm auth to the mysite page itself for each user.